# Remove duplicates from multiple columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates

I have this Table in BigQuery and I want to check the duplicates on three columns :

- CustomerID, Date1 and Product.

If the duplicate exist I need to remove it and keep the newer Date (Date1 or Date2) after comparing both of them.

for the following example the results should be:

| CustomerID | Date1 | Date2 | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5421 | 2019-02-25 | 2019-02-25 | P1 | 500 |
| 6521 | 2010-07-06 | 2019-05-04 | P2 | 1254 |
| 4124 | 2019-05-03 | 2020-06-16 | P3 | 354 |
| 5421 | 2019-02-25 | 2019-12-15 | P1 | 547 |

The Results:

| CustomerID | Date1 | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6521 | 2010-07-06 | P2 | 1254 |
| 4124 | 2019-05-03 | P3 | 354 |
| 5421 | 2019-12-15 | P1 | 547 |

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `greatest()` to order the results.  In BigQuery you can use aggregation then to get the latest record per customer:

```
select (array_agg(t order by greatest(date1, date2) limit 1))[ordinal(1)].* except (date1, date2),
       max(greatest(date1, date2)) as the_date
from t
group by customerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select as value array_agg(struct(CustomerID, greatest(Date1, Date2) as Date1, Product, Price) order by greatest(Date1, Date2) desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by CustomerID, Date1, Product
```

when applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]